# Angular - Can I use $mdDialog in Http Interceptor Service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using http interceptor to handle errors. Is it possible to use md-dialog to pop up a window showing error messages once some certain errors are captured. A `circular dependency` error occurs when injecting `$mdDialog` into the service. Where should I bind `errorMsg` if `$mdDialog` can be used in this service?

interceptor:

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$mdDialog', function($q, $mdDialog){
   return {
        'response': function(res) {
            var status = res.data.status;
            var errorMsg = res.data.payload.message;
            if(status === 'fail') {
              $mdDialog.show({
               // controller: ???,
               // scope: ???,
                templateUrl: 'error.html',
              })
              return $q.reject(res);
            } 
            return res;
        }
     }
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can display the $scope variable using a controller and resolve,

```
 $mdDialog.show({
      controller: function($scope, $mdDialog){
        // do something with dialog scope
      },
      template: '<md-dialog aria-label="My Dialog">'+
                    '<md-dialog-content class="sticky-container">{{test}}' +
                    '</md-dialog-content>' +
                    '<md-button ng-click=close()>Close</md-button>' +
                    '</md-dialog>',
      controller: 'modalCtrl',
       resolve: {
        test: function () {
          return 'test variable';
        }
      }
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('modalCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, test) {
  $scope.test = test;
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9c8d4v?p=info)

Comment: i think his problem is if he can use it inside a httpInterceptor that is declared on the configure path of angular

Comment: You've got `controller` twice in `$mdDialog.show()`

Comment: Yes @PauloGaldoSandoval

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval use a controller as above and get the data from the service